# Gunicorn not starting throwing gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. error

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, server, gunicorn

I'm trying a deploy simple Django application on Digital Ocean by following this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04) I follow every work step by step and successfully run that project via python manage.py runserver where it's not throwing any error but when I try to implement it with gunicorn its throw following error

> gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

Here is my following configuration:

**sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

**sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=pos
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/pos/pos
ExecStart=/home/pos/env/bin/gunicorn \
          --access-logfile - \
          --workers 3 \
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \
          pos.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket**

```
● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (listening) since Tue 2019-11-26 07:39:39 UTC; 12min ago
   Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
   CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

Nov 26 07:39:39 POS systemd[1]: Listening on gunicorn socket.
```

When I try to start gunicorn it's throwing this error

**sudo systemctl status gunicorn**

```
● gunicorn.service - gunicorn daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-11-26 07:39:43 UTC; 13min ago
  Process: 718 ExecStart=/home/pos/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock pos.wsgi:application (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 718 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS gunicorn[718]:     Arbiter(self).run()
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS gunicorn[718]:   File "/home/pos/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 198, in run
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS gunicorn[718]:     self.start()
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS gunicorn[718]:   File "/home/pos/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 155, in start
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS gunicorn[718]:     self.LISTENERS = sock.create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log, fds)
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS gunicorn[718]:   File "/home/pos/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 172, in create_sockets
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS gunicorn[718]:     sock_name = sock.getsockname()
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS gunicorn[718]: OSError: getsockaddrlen: bad family
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 26 07:39:43 POS systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Anyone helps me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The latest version of gunicorn (20.0.3) can cause this [problem](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2207).

Try installing an older version of gunicorn:

```
pip install gunicorn==20.0.2
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that you are trying to listen to `unix:/run/gunicorn.sock` in `ExecStart`, but the socket is at `run/gunicorn.socket`. Try changing this and run `systemctl daemon-reload` to see if it makes a difference.